# What is a standard approach to binarize microarray gene expression data?

Tags: r, microarray, data-preprocessing

I am using gene expression data from a microarray dataset for the purpose of learning the network structure of genes in the dataset.

Now to do this I need to binarize my data, i.e convert the data for each gene to 0s and 1s. I am new to bioinformatics and am not sure what approach is considered standard for microarray data.

I appreciate your inputs regarding this and I am implementing this in R. So if you know any package that does this please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the info you provide, [ArrayBin](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ArrayBin/ArrayBin.pdf) R package provides you the necessary tools:

- `binarize.array()` from [ArrayBin](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ArrayBin/ArrayBin.pdf), allowing:

> Implementation of an adaptive method for binarizing gene expression data on a per-probe basis and demonstrate the superior effectiveness of our method when compared with other, commonly used approaches. This adaptive binarization method can be applied to DNA methylation microarray data,
>   which has implications for cross-platform integration, and can reduce batch effects in the data.

In complement, I'd advise you go through some literature and choose the approach which fits you best. Some suggestions:

- [Computational analysis of microarray data](https://www.nature.com/articles/35076576)
- [Binary matrix factorization for analyzing gene expression data](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10618-009-0145-2)
- and probably most relevant for you given your application: [Multiscale Binarization of Gene Expression Data for Reconstructing Boolean Networks](http://sci-hub.tw/10.1109/tcbb.2011.62)

Maybe you also want to look into more general concepts of transformation prior to microarray data analysis:

- [Microarray data normalization and transformation](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~zivbj/class05/reading/norm.pdf)
- [A Tutorial Review of Microarray Data Analysis](http://www.ub.edu/stat/docencia/bioinformatica/microarrays/ADM/slides/A_Tutorial_Review_of_Microarray_data_Analysis_17-06-08.pdf)